# Add field in DataObject in PowerBuilder

Tags: field, powerbuilder, datawindow

I am new to PowerBuilder and I need to add a new column to a DataObject. The DataObject has several fields which retrieves data using select statement. So if I add a column in the select statement I get another field with a name `compute_0041` along with the added column field. When i try to remove the `compute_0041` field I cannot see any value in the field representing a new column. How do I remove the `compute_0041` that gets automatically added?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Datawindow if you accidentally put a `0` or `''` in one of the rows in the tab called Computed Columns then these columns may come in. Of course, you can also have a computed column yourself by specifying it there but since it seems you think you didnt do anything and it came up on its own it appears to be an accidental issue.

You can of course check for it by going to the SQL mode and checking for it there. Also, the last tab in the design view it shows the complete generated SQL where you can easily see a select column that is not chosen by you.

Hope the above will aid you to identify the issue. Please let me know if you still have the issue.

Comment: Thanks you are right. The query had a 0 in it and thank you for posting the answer.